# A public action method 'FetchClaimsFor?pn=11111&cm=12&cy=2016' was not found on controller 'MyAPP.Controllers.ClaimMonthController'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

I have a View that has an Http.Action to get a partial View.

My View has the following:

```
    @Code
        ViewData("Title") = "View Claims"
        Dim actionUrl As String = "FetchClaimsFor?pn=" & ViewData("PersonnelNo") & "&cm=" & ViewData("ClaimMonth") & "&cy=" & ViewData("ClaimYear")
    End Code

    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        @Html.Action(actionUrl, "ClaimMonth")
    </div>
```

My ClaimMonthController has the following:

```
    <HttpGet>
    <ChildActionOnly>
    Function FetchClaimsFor() As PartialViewResult

        Dim pn As String = Request.QueryString("pn")
        Dim cm As Integer = Request.QueryString("cm")
        Dim cy As Integer = Request.QueryString("cy")

        Dim ClaimsMade = New OvertimeClaims

        ClaimsMade.GetClaimsFor(pn, cm, cy)

        Select Case tsbClaimsMade.CoreDays

            Case 0
                Return PartialView("_TSB0", OvertimeClaims)
            Case 5
                Return PartialView("_TSB5", tsbClaimsMade)
            Case 6
                Return PartialView("_TSB6", tsbClaimsMade)
            Case 8
                Return PartialView("_TSB8", tsbClaimsMade)
            Case Else
                Return PartialView("_TSB0", tsbClaimsMade)

        End Select

    End Function
```

I did this approach as the partialview can be one of 4 types based on a value returned in the ClaimsMade object.

Unfortunately I'm getting the error...

> A public action method 'FetchClaimsFor?pn=11111&cm=12&cy=2016' was not
>   found on controller 'MyAPP.Controllers.ClaimMonthController'.

Looking at other similar question in SO I have tried with and without `<HttpGet>` and with and without `<ChildActionOnly>` - each time I get the same error.

**UPDATE**
forgot to mention I also tried adding `Public` to the function

**SOLUTION**

View code should be:

```
@Html.Action("FetchClaimsFor", "ClaimMonth", New With { .pn = ViewData("PersonnelNo"), .cm = ViewData("ClaimMonth"), .cy = ViewData("ClaimYear") })
```

Controller code should be:

```
Function FetchClaimsFor(pn As String, cm As Integer, cy As Integer) As PartialViewResult

    REMOVE the next three lines.
    Dim pn As String = Request.QueryString("pn")
    Dim cm As Integer = Request.QueryString("cm")
    Dim cy As Integer = Request.QueryString("cy")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first param to `Html.Action` is not a URL, but rather an action name. You're correctly being told that there's no action that matches `FetchClaimsFor?pn=11111&cm=12&cy=2016`. Instead, you should be doing:

```
@Html.Action("FetchClaimsFor", "ClaimMonth", New With { .pn = ViewData("PersonnelNo"), .cm = ViewData("ClaimMonth"), .cy = ViewData("ClaimYear") })
```

*Note: I'm not fluent in VB, so the syntax may be off*

Comment: Chris, Thanks... this makes sense and I've used similar with a single parameter id but this has three parameters... Currently with your suggestion implemented I still get the same error. What changes to the controller code do I need to make? As using Request.QueryString("pn") will now give nothing (I think... not getting that far).

Comment: Sorted.... have posted all relavent changes in my question.... Thanks for your help.

Comment: FWIW, you should accept the query string params as action params, rather than trying to pull them out of `Request.QueryString`.